# When using adjustpan in an activity keyboard hides with blinking

Tags: android, android-edittext, adjustpan

I am facing issue with adjustPan in an activity where i am using multiple ediText. Now, the problem is that when i am using adjusPan for that activity and when keyboard hides the activity is blinking and goes up and down.

If i not used adjustPan then it not blinks the activity when keyboard close but my editText is hide by keyboard.

I also tried adjustResize for that activity but it shows only one editText which is focusable when keyboard is open.

So, if you have any suggestion regarding this issue please share with me...Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```